# SQL Server 2008 Datetime convert to seconds/miliseconds

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime, converters, milliseconds

--`Datetime format = '2013-10-21 12:12:12.000'`
--Obviously poor syntax but you can see what Im trying to do

```
select personnum, convert(decimal, shiftEndDate, 4)-convert(decimal, ShiftStartDate, 4) as ShiftInSeconds
from dbo.Time
where shiftStartDate between '2013-10-14 00:00:00.000' and '2013-10-20 23:59:59.000'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [DATEFROMPARTS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213228.aspx) to create `date` type from `shiftEndDate` and then cast you condition strings to date/datetime (sql server should do this automatically, if no - use [CAST/CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx))